# Can't telnet to port 3389 on computer on same network

Tags: networking, windows-8, windows-8.1, remote-desktop, firewall

I have two Windows 8.1 pro computers on the same network using the same FIOS router. On the first computer, I can telnet to `localhost 3389`. On the second computer, I can't telnet to the first's IP address or host name port 3389.

I disabled Windows firewall on the first. Temporarily disabled AVG. Exited spybot resident.

I made sure that windows firewall allows RDC through it.

What else can be blocking the remote desktop connection?

I also tried ports 81 and 8082. They have IIS websites running on them. I can't telnet to either.

What else can be blocking these ports?

Comment: Are these on wired or wireless computers? Are they both on the same side of the router? (i.e.: Both on LAN side?) If one or both are wireless, check your router for a feature called something like "Wireless Client Isolation". You might also want to try PowerShell as an alternative for testing the ports. `Test-NetConnection 128.159.1.1 -Port 3389`. This does both a ping and TCP connect test.

Comment: Both are wireless and I used to be able to rdc between them. Will take a look at the link

Comment: They were on the same router. I put my own router between the FIOS router and my own. Connected both devices to the new router wirelessly. Same issue. i think its time to uninstall AVG to see if it makes a difference